# Rails: Convert a complex SQL query to Arel or ActiveRecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arel

In a Rails app I'm working on, I've set up a scope on a Newsletter Author model which uses a complex query I've figured out in raw SQL like so:

```
scope :without_submissions_for, lambda { |newsletter_id|
  query = <<~SQL.squish
    SELECT * FROM "newsletter_authors"
    WHERE "newsletter_authors"."discarded_at" IS NULL
    AND "newsletter_authors"."newsletter_id" = :newsletter_id
    AND "newsletter_authors"."group_member_id" IN (
      SELECT DISTINCT "group_members"."id" FROM "group_members"
      INNER JOIN "newsletter_stories" ON "newsletter_stories"."author_id" = "group_members"."id"
      WHERE "newsletter_stories"."author_id" = "group_members"."id"
      AND "newsletter_stories"."status" = 'draft'
      AND NOT (
        EXISTS (
          SELECT 1 FROM "newsletter_stories"
          WHERE "newsletter_stories"."author_id" = "group_members"."id"
          AND "newsletter_stories"."status" = 'submitted'
        )
      )
    );
  SQL
  find_by_sql([query, newsletter_id: newsletter_id])
}
```

This does exactly what I need it to, which, along with some context (models below) is this: A Group has Members and Newsletters. Some of those members can be authors for a given newsletter. Those authors can write stories for the newsletter, and each story can be in *Draft*, *Submitted* (for publication), *Published* or *Retracted* state. Draft stories may or may not be assigned to a specific newsletter, but stories in all other states are assigned to a single newsletter. This query identifies authors assigned to a specific newsletter who have drafts written but no submitted stories to that newsletter.

I'd love to figure out how to translate this to Arel or Active Record statements for better consistency with elsewhere in the codebase. I cannot quite wrap my head around all the details of making that happen, particularly around setting up the subquery correctly.

**EDIT:** Changed the query to sanitize the `newsletter_id` argument, as per @Eyeslandic's suggestion.

**EDIT 2:** Here are the models I'm working with here, condensed for clarity. Remember, the scope above is on the `Newsletter::Author` model:

`group.rb`

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members, class_name: 'GroupMember'
  has_many :newsletters
end
```

`group_member.rb`

```
class GroupMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group
  has_many :authorships, inverse_of: :group_member, class_name: "Newsletter::Author"
  has_many :stories, inverse_of: :author, class_name: "Newsletter::Story"
end
```

`newsletter.rb`

```
class Newsletter < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :authors, inverse_of: :newsletter
  has_many :stories
end
```

`newsletter/author.rb`

```
class Newsletter::Author < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :newsletter, inverse_of: :authors
  belongs_to :group_member, class_name: "GroupMember", inverse_of: :authorships
end
```

`newsletter/story.rb`

```
class Newsletter::Story < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :newsletter, inverse_of: :stories, optional: true
  belongs_to :author, inverse_of: :stories, class_name: "GroupMember"

  enum status: {draft: "draft", submitted: "submitted", published: "published"}, _default: "draft"
end
```

Comment: Please post your models code

Comment: Start step-by-step, `NewsletterAuthor.where(discardet_at: nil)` and so on. Try building the subquery on its own and then adding it to the main query. You will get there.

Comment: Then again, there is really nothing wrong with using SQL as you are now. You might just want to make sure the input is sanitized with `Model.find_by_sql(["select * from table where id = :newsletter_id", newsletter_id: newsletter_id])` to not introduce sql injection.

Comment: Excellent points both, @Eyeslandic. I've changed it to sanitize the input, and will try breaking it down statement by statement.

Comment: I've added in the models, @LyzardKyng.

Comment: @max - Thanks for dropping by - you helped me out with a related question a few months back! Anyway, a Group has Members and Newsletters. Some of those members can be authors for a given newsletter. Those authors can write stories for the newsletter, and each story can be in Draft, Submitted (for publication), or Published state. Draft stories may or may not be assigned to a specific newsletter, but submitted and published ones are. This query is supposed to identify authors of a newsletter who have drafts written but no submissions to a specific newsletter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While we can certainly build your query in Arel, after reviewing your SQL a bit it looks like it would actually be much cleaner to simply build this using the AR API instead.

The following should produce the exact query you are looking for (sans `"newsletter_stories"."author_id" = "group_members"."id"` because this is already implied by the join)

```
class Newsletter::Author < Application Record
  belongs_to :newsletter, inverse_of: :authors
  belongs_to :group_member, class_name: "GroupMember", inverse_of: :authorships
  scope :without_submissions_for, ->(newsletter_id) {
    group_members = GroupMember
         .select(:id)
         .joins(:stories)
         .where(newsletter_stories: {status: 'draft'})
         .where.not( 
           Newsletter::Story
            .select(1)
            .where(status: 'submitted')
            .where(Newsletter::Story.arel_table[:author_id].eq(GroupMember.arel_table[:id]))
            .arel.exists
         ).distinct
    where(discarded_at: nil, newsletter_id: newsletter_id, group_member_id: group_members)
  }
end
```

Comment: Wow, @engineersmnky, this is fantastic! Thank you so much for stepping through this. I did have to make a couple of tweaks to your AR query to get it to work, but it's all there. First `NewsletterStory` is namespaced `Newsletter::Story`, and the `.exists` clause had to be piped through Arel (`.arel.exists`) in order to appropriately wrap that subquery in an EXISTS statement.

Comment: Also, I really appreciate the simplicity of breaking out the `group_members` query into a separate query and then using the results in a simple `where`. I was thinking of it as one large nested query with the group member lookup as a subquery, but this is so much simpler to reason about. Thanks again!